# PowerShell script error "Unexpected token 'h' in expression or statement. The string is missing the terminator:"

Tags: c#, string, powershell

I have the following code inside my console application to get a server information using PowerShell:

```
string PsCmd = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" + vCenterName.Trim() + "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername.Trim() + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword + "';" + System.Environment.NewLine;

PsCmd = PsCmd + "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;

PsCmd = PsCmd + "Get-VMHost " + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

Now the script is working well on the 150 servers we have, but on a single server I am getting this exception:

> At line:1 char:131 + ... !********(********6'***;*****'; + ~
>   Unexpected token 'h' in expression or statement. At line:1 char:135 +
>   ... *****(******'*;*'; + ~~ The string is missing the terminator: '. |
>   ABC

Which is raising an error on the password variable. And in my case I am getting the password from an external RESP API. Now the password have this format:

```
\"************
```

Where it starts with 2 reserved characters `\"`, and the JSON object which I get will be as follow `{"PASSWORD":"\"*******"}`.. so could the problem be that the password contains reserved set of characters `\"`?? And how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the password have this format:
>
> ```
> \"*******
> ```
>
> Where it starts with 2 reserved characters `\"`

If your passwords really come from JSON such as `{"PASSWORD":"\"*******"}`, **your passwords do *not* start with `\"` - they start with `"`**, because the `\` is simply a JSON *escape character* needed to embed a literal `"` in char. in an (always double-quoted) JSON string value.

In other words: If you parse your JSON correctly, the actual password value will be:

```
"*******
```

You can verify this as follows:

```
PS> ('{ "PASSWORD": "\"*******" }' | ConvertFrom-Json).PASSWORD
"*******
```

---

Your next problem is that **you're embedding the password in a string representing *PowerShell source code***, and inside that string you're using (embedded) ***single-quoting* (`'...'`)** to surround the value<sup>[1]</sup>.
In order to do that, **you must escape value-embedded `'` instances as `''`** so as not to cause a syntax error when PowerShell later parses the code:

```
// Note the .Replace() calls
string PsCmd = "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" +
  vCenterName.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + 
  vCenterUsername.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + 
  "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword.Replace("'", "''") + "';" + 
  System.Environment.NewLine;
```

With a literal password value of `"***'***` (and sample values for the center and username), C# variable `PSCmd` will receive a string with the following *literal contents*:

```
add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = 'center1';$vCenterAdmin = 'jdoe' ;$vCenterPassword = '"***''***';
```

---

<sup>[1] And single quotes *are* the right choice, because using double quotes could result in unwanted interpretation (string interpolation) of the embedded value by PowerShell.</sup>

Comment: now your code work for me also.. where i simple replace   `vCenterPassword` with `vCenterPassword.Replace("'", "''")`.. but i am not sure how your replace method worked exactly? as having two `''` instead of one `'` should produce different password is this correct?

Comment: @testtest: No: By using `''` you simply _escape_ what ends up being a single `'` in the _resulting string_. It is merely a _syntax requirement_, just as `\"` in the JSON input was necessary to produce a literal `"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `"`. You do this in PowerShell using the `` ` `` character, e.g. `` `" ``

Try this:

```
string PsCmd = "Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" + vCenterName.Trim() + "'; $vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername.Trim() + "'; $vCenterPassword = \"" + vCenterPassword.Replace("\"", "`\"") + "\";" + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: can you please explain this in more details? what i need to do inside my code?

Comment: thanks for the edit,, so in this case the `"` inside the password will be replaced by `"  ??

Comment: @JonGrant but if the " is going to be replaced by `" so this will produce wrong password?

Comment: @testtest No, the `` is ignored. Is it possible the password contains a single quote? `'` In this case, perhaps change the code as per my edited example

Comment: @JonGrant i tried to add your code, but still i am getting the exact same error.. where the password will be as follow inside my visula studio debug $vCenterPassword = '`\"*********';

Comment: now the password seems to have many special charecters the password is as follow:-   \"!*****_*(******'**;*******

Comment: Now your updated code seems to work well for me.. although I  got lost what is the problem and how you fix it ?

Comment: @testtest your password had a special character in it, so for example you were generating $pw = "abc"123" - this is invalid, it has to have the ` character before the second ".